# Opening Camera even when permission is denied

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

How is this Code opening the camera even when I denied the permission?

MANIFEST FILE:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

JAVA FILE:

```
 public void emojifyMe(View view) {
    // Check for the external storage permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // If you do not have permission, request it
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},1 );
    } else {
        // Launch the camera if the permission exists
        launchCamera();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // Called when you request permission to read and write to external storage
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // If you get permission, launch the camera
                launchCamera();
            } else {
                // If you do not get permission, show a Toast
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                launchCamera();
                //*** But see here I am getting my work done here then whats this Runtime Permission exactly??
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It opens the camera but it shouldn't since the permission is denied.What is the possible cause?

Comment: your code snippet shows a calendar permission request. It can't be told whether the camera permission has been granted

Comment: What do you actually do in `launchCamera()`?

Comment: opens the camera via camera-intent